# Getting the list of installed root CA on an android device

Tags: android, ca

is there a way that i can get the **current** list of Root CA's installed on an android Device?

Answer (score 0):

System certificates are stored in /system/etc/security/cacerts. Users certificates are stored in /data/misc/keychain/certs-added.

Comment: so can i see them as a non-system app?
system or user certs?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no API to get this information so you must be system or root app to access it